# What's happening in this Perl foreach loop?

Tags: perl

I have this Perl code:

```
foreach (@tmp_cycledef)
{
 chomp;
 my ($cycle_code, $close_day, $first_date) = split(/\|/, $_,3);
 $cycle_code =~ s/^\s*(\S*(?:\s+\S+)*)\s*$/$1/;
 $close_day  =~ s/^\s*(\S*(?:\s+\S+)*)\s*$/$1/;
 $first_date =~ s/^\s*(\S*(?:\s+\S+)*)\s*$/$1/;

 #print "$cycle_code, $close_day, $first_date\n";
 $cycledef{$cycle_code} = [ $close_day, split(/-/,$first_date) ];
}
```

The value of `tmp_cycledef` comes from output of an SQL query:

```
select cycle_code,cycle_close_day,to_char(cycle_first_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')
  from cycle_definition d
  order by cycle_code;
```

What exactly is happening inside the `for` loop?

Comment: If you can give the sample output of sql, answering will be more easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huh, I'm surprised no one fixed it for you :)

It looks like the person who wrote this was trying to trim leading and trailing whitespace from each field. It's a really odd way to do that, and for some reason he was overly concerned with interior whitespace in each field despite his anchors.

I think that should be the same as trimming the whitespace around the delimiter in the [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

```
foreach (@tmp_cycledef)
    {
    s/^\s+//; s/$//; #leading and trailing whitespace on the whole string
    my ($cycle_code, $close_day, $first_date) = split(/\s*\|\s*/, $_, 3);

    $cycledef{$cycle_code} = [ $close_day, split(/-/,$first_date) ];
    }
```

The key to thinking about `split` is considering which parts of the string you want to throw away, not just what separates the fields that you want.

Answer (score 0):

For regex part, `s/^\s*(\S*(?:\s+\S+)*)\s*$/$1/` do stripping of leading and trailing whitespaces

Comment: $variable =~ s/something/somethingelse/ 

that is a substitution regex that finds something and replaces it with something else: there's plenty of stuff on regex's are formatted on the web.

Comment: Trimming whitespace is much easier with Scalar::Util::trim.

Answer (score 0):

Each row in `@tmp_cycledef` is composed of a string formatted following "cycle_code | close_day | first_date".

```
my ($cycle_code, $close_day, $first_date) = split(/\|/, $_,3);
```

Split the string into three parts. The following regular expressions are used to strip leading and trailing whitespaces.

The last instruction of the loop creates an entry in the dictionary `$cycledef` indexed by `$cycle_code`. The entry is formated is formatted using the following scheme:

```
[ $close_day, YYYY, MM, DD ]
```

where `$first_date = "YYYY-MM-DD"`.

Answer (score 0):

`@tmp_cycledef`: The output of the sql query is stored in this array

`foreach (@tmp_cycledef)` : For every element in this array.

`chomp :` remove the \n char from the end of every element.

```
my ($cycle_code, $close_day, $first_date) = split(/\|/, $_,3);
```

split the elements into 3 parts and assign the variable to each of the splited element. parts of split are "split(/PATTERN/,EXPR,LIMIT)"

```
$cycle_code =~ s/^\s*(\S*(?:\s+\S+)*)\s*$/$1/;
$close_day =~ s/^\s*(\S*(?:\s+\S+)*)\s*$/$1/;
$first_date =~ s/^\s*(\S*(?:\s+\S+)*)\s*$/$1/;
```

This regex part is sripping of leading and trailing whitespaces from each variable.

Comment: why down vote??  If you think any issue with answer why you are not putting it here?

Answer (score -1):

my god, it's been such a long time since I've read perl... but I'll give it a shot.

you grab a record from @tmp_cycledef, and chomp off the newline at the end, and split it up into the three variables: then, like S.Mark said, each substitution regex strips off the leading and trailing whitespace for each of the three variable. Finally, the values get pushed into a hash as a list, with some debugging code commented out right above it.

hth

Comment: $cycledef{$cycle_code} = [ $close_day, split(/-/,$first_date) ]; can you tell me what is happening in this line?

Answer (score -1):

- Your query gives a set of rows that
  are stored in the array
  `@tmp_cycledef`.
- We iterate over each row in the
  result using: `foreach
  (@tmp_cycledef)`.
- The result rows might have trailing
  newline char, we get rid of them
  using `chomp`.
- Next we `split` the row (which is not
  in `$_`) on the pipe and assign the
  first 3 pieces to `$cycle_code`,
  `$close_day` and `$first_date`
  respectively.
- The split pieces might have leading
  and trailing white spaces, the next 3
  lines are to remove the leading and
  trailing white space in the 3
  variables.
- Finally we make an entry into the
  hash `%cycledef`. The key use is
  `$cycle_code` and the value is an
  array whose first element is
  `$close_day` and rest of the elements
  are pieces got after splitting
  `$first_date` on hyphen.